# Integration between Amazon S3 and QGIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, qgis

Does anyone know an easy way to integrate QGIS and S3 buckets? To read the files from the bucket in gis platforms directly, without download?
I was looking for the same thing for R, and I found the package flyio (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flyio/flyio.pdf) which is absolutely amazing, but still with the issue to integrate S3 and QGIS. 
If it's possible so we can move from an internal server to S3 storage for the spatial data, instead of only raw/table-based data.

Thanks all in advance for ideas and feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 is specifically supported as a remote protocol, but [others](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337252/26375) have shown that if the data is public, then using HTTP(S) to access the bucket may be easiest.

Open a layer in the Data Source Manager (the red, yellow, and blue squares icon), then change to `Protocol: HTTP(S), cloud, etc.` and enter the URL ([documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#provider-based-loading-tools)).

Example URL:

```
https://example-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sweet-layer.tif
```

---

To instead use S3 via `vsis3` (public or private) or `vsicurl` (public; maybe private but complicated if so):

- [general documentation](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html)
- [`vsicurl`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsicurl-http-https-ftp-files-random-access)
- [`vsis3`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3)

The basics are that the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are required and the "bucket" is the URL with the bucket path and the "object key" is the file or folder of the layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still of interest, but our approach was using PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension in Amazon RDS to serve spatial data. Instead of storing your files in S3 storage, upload them to PostgreSQL tables. By doing so, you will also get daily snapshots of your data, better performance, the ability to query data with SQL and even set up authorization rules to match your exact needs.

It may seem a little more expensive at first, but if you find an alternate way to use S3 storage you will be using some kind of additional server which will also cost as much. Maybe some kind of software that adds S3 storage as a network attached drive works, but you will run into concurrency problems and sync issues if the files are used simultaneously by many people.

Let me know if you find a different approach. I am unaware of how you could do it.

Comment: I am looking for a way to link my AWS bucket with XYZ ({z} {x} {y} ) tiles to QGIS.  It works fine with Leaflet but I cannot get QGIS to work,   What was your PostgreSQL method of loading?